# Using JQuery to get <h3> contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I've working on trying to get the text inside a H3 tag for ages now, so I thought I would ask the community. I am using JQuery to get it, but I nothing returned when running the code.

It may be better to show what I want:

```
<a href="/eat-move-sleep/" class="teaserBoxLink _matchHeight">
  <div class="teaserBoxImage">
   <img src="/contentassets/6a53309d70054d14b988a9a45ab1c760/e43ee1c1d8ad4461802fde8ea7939a962.jpg?width=500&amp;height=200&amp;quality=90&amp;mode=crop" alt="" />
  </div>
  <h3 class="teaserBoxTitle">EAT MOVE SLEEP</h3>
</a>
```

I want to get the contents from the H3-tag (the text "EAT MOVE SLEEP") as the output.

Here is a snippet of one of many ways I've tried:

```
function(){
var ec = {{Click Element}};
var h3 = $(ec).siblings().find('h3').attr('class');
return h3;
}
```

I am grateful for any help! :)

Comment: Which element is `Click Element`?

Comment: This is Google Tag Manager, so the click element refers to the image in this case :)

Comment: Then the `h3` tag is not a sibling of the clicking element, it's a sibling of the parent element. `$(ec).parent().siblings('h3').text()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image doesn't have any siblings, do `$(ec).siblings()` is returning an empty set, and therefore `.find("h3")` doesn't find anything. The `<h3>` is a sibling of the image's parent `<div>`, so it should be:

```
var h3 = $(ec).parent().siblings("h3").text();
```

Or you could make it less dependent on the specific layout:

```
var h3 = $(ec).closest(".teaserBoxLink").find("h3").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var content = $("a.teaserBoxLink._matchHeight h3").text();
```

I think should be able to access it this way, but there may be an issue with you having an H3 INSIDE a link (`a`).